# Can I lock rotation to the "closest" rotation axis?

Tags: interface

I like having close control over how I rotate an object. So I usually only rotate along a single global or local axis at a time.

This requires me specifying the axis I want to rotate around ("r x", "r y", "r z" or, using the middle mouse button). But I often find myself rotating around the axis that is closest to the viewport normal. Is there a simple way to accomplish this that will determine the required axis itself, without me having to explicitly specify it?

*n.b.: I don't want to set the transform orientation to "viewport", I want to actually rotate around one of the global x, y, z. I also don't want to align the viewport to one of the axis first (which would require me to figure out which axis to rotate around too).*

Comment: Setting transform orientation to View and using X axis will be the fastest way to do that. To avoid double pressing X enable Trasform manipulator if you use it and click on red line to rotate the object. I don't think there's any other faster way other than scripting something